# C++ Derived class overriding member of base class with another derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class, derived

I have classes like this:

```
class ParkingLot
{
public:
    int spaces;
    virtual bool something() { return true; }
}
class ParkingLotBuilding
{
public:
    ParkingLot Floor1, Floor2;
}
```

I've got a whole lot of functions that take ParkingLotBuilding. Let's say someone (me) derives from ParkingLot and ParkingLotBuilding:

```
class DerivedParkingLot : public ParkingLot
{
public:
    virtual bool something() { return false; }
}
class DerivedParkingLotBuilding : public ParkingLotBuilding
{
public:
    // how can I make it so that Floor1 and Floor2 are for DerivedParkingLot?
}
```

I've got functions I don't control that are like this:

```
CheckBuilding( ParkingLotBuilding &building )
{
    if(building.Floor1.something() == true)
    // error
}
```

If I pass a DerivedParkingLotBuilding object to that function how do I make it so that it calls DerivedParkingLot::something() to return false? Is that possible? Sorry if I didn't explain this right I'm not sure how to ask about the problem. Thanks

Comment: you cannot override members, only methods

Comment: Adding to what JohnSmith said: Since `ParkingLotBuilding` contains `ParkingLot` values, and not `ParkingLot` pointers or references, they can't be used polymorphically, even in `DerivedParkingLot`.

Comment: @zindorsky I think this is the correct answer. If you or John wants to submit it as an answer and explain it I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JohnSmith pointed out, you can't override data members, just member functions. Since `ParkingLotBuilding` contains `ParkingLot` values, and not `ParkingLot` pointers or references, they can't be used polymorphically, even in `DerivedParkingLot`. (That's just how C++ works: only pointers and references can have a dynamic type.)

That means that if you can't change the `ParkingLotBuilding` class (or the `CheckBuilding` function), then you're stuck. There is no deriving you can do that will get the `CheckBuilding` function to operate on a `DerivedParkingLot` object.

The moral of this story is that classes must be designed for inheritance from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you just to call the DerivedParkingLot function from a ParkingLot instance ?

Your code already did it by specifiying the something method as virtual, it will automaticaly search for the lowest method in his inherited tree.

A simple way to test it is to implement the something method in ParkingLot and DerivedParkingLot, put different message in each and check it

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to approach this is by making `ParkingLot` a template class.

```
template<typename T>
class ParkingLotBuilding
{
public:
    T Floor1, Floor2;
}
```

Then when creating a `ParkingLotBuilding`, you could use these types:

```
ParkingLotBuilding<ParkingLot>
ParkingLotBuilding<DerivedParkingLot>
```

Also if you don't like templating all the time and want to just use `ParkingLotBuilding` and `DerivedParkingLotBuilding`, you could rename the class to something like `Building` and use typedefs:

```
typedef Building<ParkingLot> ParkingLotBuilding
typedef Building<DerivedParkingLot> DerivedParkingLotBuilding
```

This approach isn't exactly inheritance between the `ParkingLotBuilding` types (and may not be the best approach - I've never seen this before), but it might do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Floor1 has no way of knowing whether it was instantiated inside of ParkingLotBuilding or DerivedParkingLotBuilding.

You could use RTTI to deal with this something like:

```
CheckBuilding (ParkingLotBuilding *building)
{
    if (dynamic_cast<DerivedParkingLogBuilding*>(building))
    {
        // Floor is in a derived parking log building
    }
    else
    {
        // Floor is in a parking lot building
    }
}
```

Not exactly the best was of doing this though, as pointed out above.